# audio file isn't being played

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, isolatedstorage

An audio file is saved to isolated storage but it isn't being played when clicked. i just show my code here. The code actually gets the audio file from the xap content and stores to the isolated storage. It reads back as shown but it doesn't play as expected.

method for reading back

```
using (var ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (ISF.FileExists(MusicFileToPlay))
                {
                    using (var FS = ISF.OpenFile(MusicFileToPlay, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        mediaelement.Stop();
                        mediaelement.SetSource(FS);

                        mediaelement.Position = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                        mediaelement.Volume = 20;
                        mediaelement.Play();
                        StatusTextBlock.Text = "Playing....";
                        //MediaPlayer.Play(
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    StatusTextBlock.Text = "No file present to play....";
                }
            }
```

method for storing into isolated storage

```
private void SaveSoundsToStorage()
    {
        foreach (string music in fileNames)
        {
            string filename = String.Format("Sounds/{0}.mp3", music);
            SaveHelper(filename, music + ".mp3");
        }
    }

private void SaveHelper(string filename, string savename)
    {
        using (var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (appStorage.FileExists(savename))
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("File already exists");
                return;
            }
            StreamResourceInfo SRI = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream FS = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(savename, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, appStorage))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(FS))
                    {
                        long lg = 0;
                        Stream s;
                        try
                        {
                            if (SRI != null)
                            {
                                s = SRI.Stream;
                                lg = s.Length;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception error)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Stream resource exception:  "+error.Message);
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (lg > appStorage.AvailableFreeSpace)
                            {
                                //No space available.Request more space
                                Int64 spaceToAdd = lg;
                                Int64 curAvail = appStorage.AvailableFreeSpace;

                                // Request more quota space.
                                if (!appStorage.IncreaseQuotaTo(appStorage.Quota + spaceToAdd))
                                {
                                    // The user clicked NO to the
                                    // host's prompt to approve the quota increase.
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // The user clicked YES to the
                                    // host's prompt to approve the quota increase.
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("quota increase problem.");
                        }

                        byte[] buff = new byte[32];
                        int count = 0;
                        try
                        {
                            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(SRI.Stream))
                            {
                                while (count < lg)
                                {
                                    int actual = br.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                                    count += actual;
                                    BW.Write(buff, 0, actual);
                                    BW.Flush();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error at binary reader.");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Binarywriter exception.");
                }
                //MessageBox.Show(filename + " saved successfully.");
                StatusTextBlock.Text = savename + " saved succesfully";
            }
        }
    }
```

Media element XAML code is

```
<MediaElement Name="mediaelement" Height="120" Width="160" AutoPlay="True" MediaFailed="mediaelement_MediaFailed_1"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is a MediaElement in visual tree, like LayoutRoot.Children.Add(mediaelement) or declared in xaml?

Comment: The Xaml i gave is

    <MediaElement Name="mediaelement" Height="120" Width="160" AutoPlay="True" MediaFailed="mediaelement_MediaFailed_1"/>